# Meaning of motored up

Tags: phrasal-verbs

here is a sentence:

They motored up, taking Michael Mont, who, being in his seventh heaven, was found by Winifred 'very amusing'.

What does the phrasal verb "**motored up**" mean in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means to travel by car/automobile.

See the verb definition here:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/motor

"Up", when used with "travelling" verbs, is a loosely defined adverb. It's often used to mean north, but also can be used as meaning towards a big city/urban area from a more smaller city or more rural area, as well as other things

Comment: I was confused by "up". Didn't find that phrasal verb in dictionaries.

Comment: I guess from the names that it's from the Forsyte books. This is probably the old-fashioned British usage of 'up' meaning 'to London' where I think Winifred lived.

Comment: @BBQBoi See my edit

Comment: @Kevin yup, thank you. Kate Bunting thank you too, you're right it's an extract from some old book.